# Suggestions on Yii project structures?

Tags: yii, structure, project-structure

I am currently developing a web project using Yii framework. I'm wondering where is a good place to put all the business logic, in the Controllers, or Models(models here as in mappings from database tables to actual objects)? Both doesn't seem right. I think I might need an extra "asset" layer in between controller and models, but I have no idea how to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the suggestion is to go about using Fat Models and Thin Controllers.  So business logic in your model.  It makes it far easier to make your code re-useable.

More info here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices

If you've got a lot of custom logic, you could potentially have an "asset" layer of additional models that handled your DB models.  Depends on your specific system though …  I'm finding I do use `CFormModel` objects this way at times to map from a form with a bunch of different models to the models as needed.